# How to pipe multiple commands in a single command in Unix and Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want the o/p as list of owner and their file names , file path and the file size.
I am using two commands to get the o/p. Can anyone suggest me how to get the o/p in a single command .The commands I am using are:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4 }' > test.txt
```

This gives me the list of owner and the directory.

And the 2nd one is:

```
find . -size +100k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -sd >tets2.txt
```

This gives me the file name and size of the file .

Answer (score 0):

Sort of don't understand, do you mean pipe them both or do each commmand in same line. To do the later, you can do

```
ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4 }' > test.txt    ;   find . -size +100k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -sd >tets2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The first command returns the owner and group, not the file name. It only works for the current directory. The second command works for subdirectories also, but only for huge files. Two unrelated commands are hard to glue together, but if your goal is to prevent calling `stat` two times for a file, you can modify the following Perl script to suit your needs:

```
use feature 'say';
while (my $file = glob '*') {
    my @stats = (stat $file)[4,5,7];
    say join "\t", $file,
                   (getpwuid $stats[0])[0],
                   (getgrgid $stats[1])[0],
                   $stats[2];
}
```